# Overlaying multiple KML files on Google Maps

Tags: file, kml

Need to know the procedure for overlaying multiple KML files on a single Google Map.
The KML files intended for this can be from

Could anyone help me out in this.

Comment: Hi,

Need to know the procedure for overlaying multiple KML files on a single Google Map.
The KML files intended for this can point to different locations.
Ex:KML1 for North America & KML2 for Asia.

Could anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple.  You just use the include kml statement once for each layer you want to import.

It can slow down if you go too crazy.